# How do I style the HTML form validation error messages with CSS?

Tags: html, css, forms, validation

How do I style the HTML form validation error messages with CSS?

Answer (score 11):

Currently, there is no way to style those little validation tooltips. The only other option, which is what I have chosen to do, is to disable the browser validation all together for now and rely on my own client-side validation scripts.

According to this article:
http://blog.oldworld.fr/index.php?post/2010/11/17/HTML5-Forms-Validation-in-Firefox-4

"The simplest way to opt out is to add the **novalidate** attribute to your `<form>`. You can also set **formnovalidate** on your submit controls."

Comment: Another reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation#Customized_error_messages

Answer (score 5):

There is currently no way to achieve this.

Chrome up **until version 27** provided a native look and feel for their validation error speech bubbles. The error bubble is made up of four containing elements that are not normative elements. These four elements are style-able via pseudo-elements that apply to separate sections of the bubble:

```
::-webkit-validation-bubble
 
::-webkit-validation-bubble-arrow-clipper 

::-webkit-validation-bubble-arrow 

::-webkit-validation-bubble-message
```

With the release of Chrome v28, they removed these non-standard selectors: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=259050

Comment: Chrome's validation error bubbles don't look native to me. They look so ugly (before Chrome 15).

Comment: setting these to display:none crashes chrome

Comment: I've opened a bug for the crash, see http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=117746

Comment: If you care about fixing this on Firefox, please vote on the bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=845405

Answer (score 1):

Use pseudo selectors, as easwee said. For example, to make the form element green when valid, and red when invalid, do something like this:

```
:invalid {
    background: #ffdddd;
         }
:valid{
      background:#ddffdd;
      }
```

If you need a full reference of these, head to [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/:invalid)

Comment: This answer (as with all others) appears to miss the question. The question is not how to style the form input based on its validation status. The question is how to style the error messages that are displayed by the browser, e.g. _"Please fill out this field."_ in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

A required field will be invalid until the correct input is entered. A field that isn't required but has validation, such as a URL field, will be valid until text is entered.

```
 input:invalid { 
border:solid red;
}
```

for more info [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772367(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772367%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: This styles the *input* not the *validation message*