# How do you customize the error message generated by HTML5 by the simple_form gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, html, validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML5 form required attribute. Set custom validation message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272433/html5-form-required-attribute-set-custom-validation-message)

Simple_form has an automatic error that is generated by html5. How do you customize the content of the message to your liking?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328883/how-do-i-style-the-html-5-form-validation-error-messages-with-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't; it's specific to the browser (and related only to HTML5; unrelated to simple_form).

Comment: Does this mean that the cool HTML5 forms stuff is only useful if you have a standard form? Anything non-standard forces you to do custom validation and error messages, like in the days before HTML5?

Comment: Seems I spoke too soon. This article (http://www.alistapart.com/articles/forward-thinking-form-validation/) shows examples of using the "pattern" attribute, and putting custom messages in the "title" attribute.

Comment: You can in fact use javascript to change the messages. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272433/html5-form-required-attribute-set-custom-validation-message/5276722#5276722

Comment: You can change the text of the message, yes. You cannot change the appearance of the message.

Comment: The question as I read it was: "How do you customize the content of the message?"

Comment: I may have answered the wrong question. I see the word 'content' now, where I did not previously.

Answer (score 2):

On firefox you can either use the [`x-moz-errormessage` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/input#attr-x-moz-errormessage) or the [`title` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/HTML5/Forms_in_HTML5#Constraint_Validation).

Comment: And Chrome it seems (just tested in v32...)