# How do I style HTML5 validation errors in Firefox

Tags: css, html, firefox, validation

I've read countless articles, but I still haven't found a way to style HTML5 validation errors in Firefox.  Has anybody had any luck w/ this?  I've been able to style some nice messages in Chrome and IE (using [Webshims](http://afarkas.github.com/webshim/demos/) for IE).

I don't like the look of the messages in Firefox (see screenshot).  [This link](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=10923) doesn't sound promising.  Nor does [this one](http://blog.oldworld.fr/index.php?post/2010/11/17/HTML5-Forms-Validation-in-Firefox-4).  However, those links are a bit stale.  I'm hoping someone has figured this out for newer versions of Firefox (I'm using version 14.0.1) .

[image: HTML5 validation message in Firefox]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is... there is no answer?  I've continued searching, and I still don't see a way to style these errors in Firefox.  The good news, however, is that the latest release of Firefox (16.0.1) has cleaned-up the appearance of the prompts, and removed the ugly inner rectangle (see screenshot).  Still, it would be nice to style these w/ a custom color; perhaps white text on dark background, for example.

[image]

Comment: If you care about fixing this on Firefox, please vote on the bug: bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=845405

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how I got here, this seems an old thread. But just to be sure anyone who does pass get the right (up-to-date) answer:

Styling form errors with CSS can be done through the pseudo-selector `:invalid`

So for the Firefox error-box you can remove it using like:

```
input[type="number"]:invalid {box-shadow: none;}
```

Answer (score -2):

The same question here ==> [How do I style the HTML5 form validation error messages with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328883/how-do-i-style-the-html-5-form-validation-error-messages-with-css)

And at the moment I don't think we can design the tooltip.
You can use the novalidate attribute for your form and create your custom tooltip.

Comment: I've read that question, and it does a good job of handling Chrome w/ the webkit-validation... css classes.  It does not address Firefox.  That's why I posted a comment to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6555897/590719) .