# HTML5 - How to aply CSS to validator message

Tags: html, message, validation, required

I'm trying (with no results) to aply a simple custom width to this validator message:

[image]

How can i do it ?

**UPDATE:** I mean, the message which says "`Please select an item from the list`" we can supose it has, by default, a `width=100px` . How can i change this default width to `300px`?

Comment: sorry but I hardly see any way to help you when you just post an image with `how can i do it?`

Comment: Sorry, i edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has already been answered. You can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328883/how-do-i-style-the-html-5-form-validation-error-messages-with-css). For ease of access the code you'll need is below.

```
::-webkit-validation-bubble

::-webkit-validation-bubble-arrow-clipper 

::-webkit-validation-bubble-arrow 

::-webkit-validation-bubble-message
```

This is Chrome's implementation of styling, however it is not officially standard. Hence consider creating your own popup.

---

**Setting content of bubble**

Please consider adding what you have already attempted and what results you would expect.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].oninvalid = function(e) {
            e.target.setCustomValidity("");
            if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
                e.target.setCustomValidity("This field shouldn't be left blank/please select an option!");
            }
        };
        elements[i].oninput = function(e) {
            e.target.setCustomValidity("");
        };
    }
})
```

Comment: I've already have setted this code to a file named `custom.validation.js`. Is there any way to make a `$.css()` in this javascript file ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't. I think it's for chrome solution, which works fine for me. The problem is in Firefox... is it correct to use `::-moz-..` ?

Comment: Unfortunaly (i think) there is not a solution for firefox. My quick way to solve this was set the text of the validate error to another too short. Anyway, thank you for answers.

Comment: @JhonatanSandoval, you're right - there's been no such implementation for Firefox, Opera and other browsers. Your solution may work, but keep an eye on future developments. Maybe it's best hide a div and only show it when the user submits a form and there's a validation error. Good luck!