# CSS style for error message of email type in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have an email input here but it has display different styles in different browsers

```
<input autofocus="autofocus" id="user_email" name="user[email]" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Email')" placeholder="email" required="required" size="30" type="email" value="">
```

I can not use JS to set the CSS style for input error, so there is any way to set the CSS style for the error message?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I style the html 5 form validation error messages with css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328883/how-do-i-style-the-html-5-form-validation-error-messages-with-css)

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, You can do this by pseudo-class selectors :valid and :invalid.
Check [this link](http://demosthenes.info/blog/462/Goodbye-JQuery-Validation-HTML5-Form-Errors-With-CSS3) for additional help.

Comment: you missunderstand me, I want just apply css for error message,not input field

Comment: Well, Then if it is that. Check this link: http://www.new2html.com/website-creation/26/creating-a-cool-success-and-error-message-display-using-css