# HTML input do not allow numbers

Tags: html, input

Right now I have an input field like this:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text"/>
```

But it stills allows the input of numbers.

I want names to be input and want to display an error message when the string contains a number. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you already tried? Maybe you can add this code.

Comment: Also... is this JUST html? or are you using .net or php or java or some other type of server code?

Comment: Sry, sth went wrong with the formatting. This should be plain HTML validation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use native [HTML5 field validation](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/)

like e-mail validation ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69korujh/2/)):
`<input type="text" title="email" pattern="[^@]+@[^@]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}" />`

For your specific case you can use regexp like `pattern="[a-zA-Z]*"` ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69korujh/3/))

When you submit form it became highlighted with red border to show you validation error. In different browser it will behave slightly different.

I don't think there is standard way to override every default styling, however there are browser specific ways to do this ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328883/how-do-i-style-the-html5-form-validation-error-messages-with-css)).

For some style you can have css hooks in place for changes [see here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/)

Edit: updated fiddle.

Comment: Nice idea, but may not support older browsers.

Comment: Supported in Chrome 5+, IE10+, FF4+, Opera9.6+, Not supported in Safari.

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo A polyfill should take care of older browsers,

Comment: as Panagiotis said there are polyfills like http://modernizr.com/ to help you with that.

Comment: @Mior Right... javascript is the only way to guarantee that this validation will work regardless of browser.

Comment: Seems to be from http://blog.staffannoteberg.com/2012/03/01/html5-form-validation-with-regex/

Doesnt help me. For email just use type="email"

Comment: While the linked example is for eMail, you can edit the regex used within to fit your needs. This plus polyfills is as close to a "HTML-only" solution as you will get.

Comment: Yes sure. Unfortunately Regex like "\p{L}" does not work. "[a-zA-Z]" will break in many languages.  But if there is not a better alternative I will have to stick with it I guess.

Answer (score 7):

This should help you to type only characters:

```js
$(function() {

  $('#txtNumeric').keydown(function (e) {
  
    if (e.shiftKey || e.ctrlKey || e.altKey) {
    
      e.preventDefault();
      
    } else {
    
      var key = e.keyCode;
      
      if (!((key == 8) || (key == 32) || (key == 46) || (key >= 35 && key <= 40) || (key >= 65 && key <= 90))) {
      
        e.preventDefault();
        
      }

    }
    
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <b>Enter Text:</b>
  <input type="text" id="txtNumeric" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several options....

Regardless of the options, you will be using regular expressions in some way shape or form.

You can do it on the client side using `JavaScript`...

```js
function Validate () {

  var inputValue = document.getElementById("test").value;
  var reg = new RegExp('^\\d+$');
  var test = reg.test(inputValue);
  
  //--Do something with test--
  console.log(test);
  
}
```

```html
<input id="test" class="form-control" type="text" />
<button onClick="Validate()">Validate</button>
```

If it is just plain `HTML` with no server side code you will need to use `JavaScript`.

**EDIT**

And as far as I know this is supported in all browsers that support `JavaScript` regardless of version.

Comment: I do not want to do the validation in JavaScript. I would like to keep it in the HTML and get the neat Browser Support like a Message on wrong input.

Comment: You either need to do it using javascript on the client side or some sort of server side code.  HTML5 has the pattern attribute for text boxes but like I have said... it is only supported by modern browsers... anyone using an older browser like IE9 will not validate properly.

Comment: Thats okay for me. Support for older browsers is not a priority.

Comment: Then try Mori's pattern attribute with my regular expression '^\\d+$'  that might work for what you are trying to do.

Comment: This seems to be the Regex Pattern for Multiple Digits with a Backslash in the front?

Comment: Try ^[0-9]*$ it all depends on the RegEx engine... not all engines are built the same and I'm not familiar with the regex engine for the pattern attribute.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808590/html5-number-input-type-that-takes-only-integers

Comment: Ah okay. The problem I have is  to not allow numbers but only letters. For numbers, type="number" should work. But thanks for trying to help me :)

Comment: oh... my apologies... I missed the fact that you didn't want numbers... I thought you wanted only numbers.

Answer (score 0):

no input alows just text:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

... you can try js + action on input like onkeydown

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp

and validate by regEx (just letters)

[Regex to match only letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617797/regex-to-match-only-letters)

can better control what happens when good or bad validation. Only the alert or change color etc.