# How to prevent user to enter specific key using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface

I have a text field and I want to allow only alphabet. So I write the below Javascript method to prevent other keys. Unfortunately my text field is allowing uparrow(^). 
Can any one tell me how to restrict uparrow(^) ?

```
function onlyAlphabet(evt) {
    var theEvent = evt || window.event;
    var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;

    var keychar = String.fromCharCode(key);
    var keycheck = /[a-zA-z\s]/;

    if (!(key == 8 || key == 27 || key == 46 || key == 9 || key == 39)) // backspace delete  escape arrows
    {
        if (!keycheck.test(keychar)) {
            theEvent.returnValue = false;//for IE
            if (theEvent.preventDefault)
                theEvent.preventDefault();//Firefox
        }
    }
}
```

html code

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="form-text">Travels Name</label>
   <h:inputText value="#{bean.travelName}" maxlength="50" onkeypress="return onlyAlphabet(event)" />
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29823591/html-input-do-not-allow-numbers

Comment: Why don't use regular expression instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve that in a more simpler way like the following:

```js
function onlyAlphabet(inputVal) {
  var patt=/^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
  if(patt.test(inputVal)){
    document.getElementById('txtTravel').value = inputVal;
  }
  else{
    var txt = inputVal.slice(0, -1);
    document.getElementById('txtTravel').value = txt;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-text">Travels Name</label>
    <input id="txtTravel" type="text" maxlength="50"
     oninput="onlyAlphabet(value)" />
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script>
        function onlyAlphabet(evt) {
            var theEvent = evt || window.event;
            var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;

            var keychar = String.fromCharCode(key);
            var keycheck = /[a-zA-z\s]/;

            if (!(key == 8 || key == 27 || key == 46 || key == 9 || key == 39 || key == 94)) // backspace delete  escape arrows
            {
               
                    if (!keycheck.test(keychar)) {
                        theEvent.returnValue = false;//for IE
                        if (theEvent.preventDefault)
                            theEvent.preventDefault();//Firefox
                    }
                
                
            }
            else if(key==94)
                theEvent.preventDefault();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

   
    <input id="Text1" type="text"  onkeypress="return onlyAlphabet(event)"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Keycode for ^ is 94 .. Prevent it.. If you want to fix it yourself put
alert(key) in the code, where you will get the code for the pressed key.

Answer (score 1):

This also works

```html
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="form-text">Travels Name</label>
   <h:inputText value="#{bean.travelName}" maxlength="50" onkeypress="/[a-zA-Z]/.test(event.key) || event.preventDefault()" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant way (not supported in Safari) is to use the `pattern` attribute of the `input` element.

```
<input pattern="[A-Za-z\s\^]+" type="text" />
```

Read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp)

<del>For the `javascript` approach, codes for arrow keys are:


    {
      left_arrow   : 37,
      up_arrow     : 38,
      right_arrow  : 39,
      down_arrow  : 40
    }

In your if condition you have to eliminate 38 and 40.</del>

Oh, you mean the ^ itself? :)))

It is enough to update your regular expression:

```
var keycheck = /[a-zA-z\s\^]/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, simple & elegant :

```
jQuery('#id').on('keypress', limitChars);

function limitChars(e){
     return event.charCode >= 97 && event.charCode <= 122;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to block only the specific key you don't want. So **keypress** event get the pressed key before this character enter in your input. You also can use **event.preventDefault()** to block this specific key you don't want.

I'll show you a good example of how this could be done using jQuery.

```
$("input[name='yourinput']").keypress(function(event) {
    if ( event.keyCode == 94 ) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation as well. Code-only answers are discouraged.