# Styling Browser Validation For All Modern Browsers

Tags: html, css

I have seen with the more modern browsers that they are automatically starting to validate forms with the new HTML attributes that you can place on them.

What I would like to know is how can we style the auto browser validation for forms so that they all look the same?

So what is the CSS for: **Firefox, Chrome, IE, Opera, Safari** +any other browser.

I am looking to do this with pure CSS.

Here is some sample HTML:

```
<form>
E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" required="required" /> <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ub5wzyhe/)

Thanks
Andrew

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I style the HTML5 form validation error messages with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328883/how-do-i-style-the-html5-form-validation-error-messages-with-css)

Comment: @Juhana That one explains how to do it for webkit, which is chrome and safari. there is no explanation for other browsers such as firefox.

Comment: That's because it's not possible to do on other browsers AFAIK, as the comments in the duplicate say.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="email" name="email" required="required" />
```

does not support IE 8 and 9

you can see the list of supported tags for different browser in

[how well does your browser support html5?](http://html5test.com/compare/browser/index.html)

But if you want to customize alert messages in other browsers you can refer this link
[Data forvalidation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation)