# HTML change text box warning colour

Tags: html, css

I am able to change an HTML text box's warning text when the input fails a pattern with:

```
<input type="text" value="" pattern="(\d|(\d,\d{0,2}))" title="YOUR_WARNING_TEXT" >
```

But how could I change the colour of the warning?  I haven't been able to find out how, if this is possible, in either html or css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you can't change styles of validation error messages. To achieve it,  you need to disable html5 default validation and use other javascript validation libraries.

[How do I style the HTML5 form validation error messages with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328883/how-do-i-style-the-html5-form-validation-error-messages-with-css)