# Is there a way to change the default icon & text formatting of setCustomValidity with CSS, jQuery, or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Just did a lot of searching but found no solution for this question. So is there any latest updates or discovery that we can change the default icon and text formatting for the `setCustomValidity` with `CSS`, `jQuery`, or `JavaScript` (see screenshot below)?

I tried `$("#txtOrganization")[0].setCustomValidity("<b>Organization name</b> is required.");` but no luck. Also, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6555897/2200913), the following is **outdated**:

```
::-webkit-validation-bubble

::-webkit-validation-bubble-arrow-clipper 

::-webkit-validation-bubble-arrow 

::-webkit-validation-bubble-message
```

Thanks!

[image: Change default icon and formatting of 'setCustomValidity'.]

Comment: I don't believe what you're trying to do is possible with the native validation notification. You'll need to build your own tools for it if you want to change the UI

Comment: reopening since dupes are really old

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : Yup, I know, just want to save some work by simply modifying the styles whenever possible. The default behavior is useful when you have a longer form and showing error message above the form will not be visible to the user. Redoing similar feature will be lot of work though.

Comment: @mplungjan : Yeah... many answers were posted in **2011**, which no longer valid. Thanks for reopening!